# SIGSEGV Error in Simple Dynamic Programming on SPOJ

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am just beginning with dynamic programming, and I have just attempted a simple question based on DP, on Spoj. Link - http://www.spoj.com/problems/MST1/

Here is the question statement -

> On a positive integer, you can perform any one of the following 3
>   steps.
>
> 1.)  Subtract 1 from it. ( n = n - 1 )
>
> 2.)  If its divisible by 2, divide by 2. ( if n % 2 == 0 , then n = n / 2  )
>
> 3.)  If its divisible by 3, divide by 3. ( if n % 3 == 0 , then n = n / 3  )
>
> Given a positive integer  n and you task is find the minimum number of
>   steps that takes n to one.
>
> Input:
>
> The input contains an integer T (1 ≤  T ≤  100) number of test cases.
>   Second line input is N (0 < N ≤ 2*10^7 ) that indicates the positive
>   number.
>
> Output:
>
> For each case, print the case number and minimum steps.

Here's my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Memo Function returns the smallest number of steps possible for integer a

int memo(int a, int mem[]);

int mem[20000010];

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%i", &t);
    for(int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
        int n;
        scanf("%i", &n);
        memset(mem, -1, sizeof(mem));
        mem[1] = 0;
        printf("Case %i: %i\n", i, memo(n, mem));   
    }
    return 0;
}

int memo(int a, int mem[]) {
    if (mem[a] != -1) return mem[a]; // If the value of smallest steps have already been calculated
    int r; // Current Lowest number of steps
    r = memo(a - 1, mem) + 1;
    if (a % 2 == 0) r = min(r, memo(a/2, mem) + 1);
    if (a % 3 == 0) r = min(r, memo(a/3, mem) + 1);
    mem[a] = r;
    return r;
}
```

I have looked up this error on the internet and here on StackOverflow, and I have found that it may occur when we are trying to access the memory that has not been allocated, for example accessing the 11th element of a 10 element array. But I don't think that's the case here.

Also, I think the upper limit of the question is 2*10^7, also the array is global, so it shouldn't be an issue. Maybe there's some issue in the way I am using the memset function? I really don't know!

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DP idea is correct but your code is not working for a large inputs (e.g. 1x10^6, or the upper boundary, 2x10^7).

By changing your code a little, you can pre-compute every answer and then output only the ones you are interested in. It will be not very time-consuming because of the dynamic programming fashion of the problem, i.e., a complex problem can be solved as a combination of one or more previously solved problems.

```
int main() 
{
    // Initialize DP array
    memset(mem, -1, sizeof(mem));
    mem[1] = 0;

    // Pre-compute every possible answer
    for(int i = 2; i <= 20000000; i++)
        mem[i] = memo(i);

    // Read the number of test cases
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    // Print only the desired answer, ie, mem[n]
    for(int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", i, mem[n]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got an ACCEPTED with this approach.

Another tip: since your DP array is global, you do not have to pass it to the DP function every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marcelo! From what I understand, here we are using from bottom to top approach, right? And in my code, we are computing the solutions in the array from top to bottom. 
And although this solution is certainly more clean, but what I don't understand is why didn't my solution work? Still, thanks again! I owe you one!